# Difference between "\(string)" and string?

Tags: swift

```
    callfunc(string: "\(string)")

    callfunc(string: string)
```

I am calling the same function with same string value but different approach....
let me know what is the difference in it? and also I want to know in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: [Swift Language Guide: String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

callfunc(string: string)

In the above syntax its a normal function call with a string.

callfunc(string: "(string)")

But here when we will pass "(string)" as a parameter, internally "(string)" creates a new string and pass it as a parameter. So in that particular point of time the memory will go high because of memory allocation for the string, which will again deallocated immediately.

Normally you won't be able to observe it with a small string, but if you will convert an image into base64 and try to pass it as a string. you can able to see the difference.

Apart from that there is no difference in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

there is no difference, `"\()"` is used if your string is something like

```
let someInt: Int = 20
print("my integer is \(someInt)") //"my integer is 20"
```

i.e. not `String` in first place.

there is no memory difference because `String` in `Swift` is not reference type, it is `Struct`, so you pass copy of `string` to your `callfunc`, not reference to it.

Comment: thre's a difference, if your string variable is implicitly unwrapped optional. In this case you're passing "Optional(string)" as string value

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference when your string is implicitly unwrapped optional. Consider example:

```
func some(string: String)
{
    print(string)
}

let string: String! = "s"

some(string: string)
some(string: "\(string)")
```

The output will be:

```
s
Optional("s")
```